# Python grpcio-tools and yandex speechkit

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpcio, speechkit

i have a problem. I try `pip install speechkit` and have a problem with `grpcio-tools`.

```
PS G:\PyPro\YaTextToVoice> pip install speechkit
Collecting speechkit 
  Using cached speechkit-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting boto3 
  Using cached boto3-1.26.89-py3-none-any.whl (134 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from speechkit) (2.28.2) 
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio-tools>=1.39.0 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from speechkit) (1.51.3)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf~=3.19.6 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from speechkit) (3.19.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pyjwt>=2.1.0 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from speechkit) (2.6.0)
Collecting cryptography 
  Using cached cryptography-39.0.2-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
Collecting grpcio-tools>=1.39.0 
  Using cached grpcio_tools-1.51.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
  Using cached grpcio_tools-1.50.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
  Using cached grpcio_tools-1.49.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
  Using cached grpcio-tools-1.48.2.tar.gz (2.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.48.2 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from grpcio-tools>=1.39.0->speechkit) (1.51.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from grpcio-tools>=1.39.0->speechkit) (49.6.0)
Collecting botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.89
  Using cached botocore-1.29.89-py3-none-any.whl (10.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from boto3->speechkit) (1.0.1)
Collecting s3transfer<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Using cached s3transfer-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cryptography->speechkit) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests->speechkit) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests->speechkit) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests->speechkit) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests->speechkit) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.89->boto3->speechkit) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography->speechkit) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.89->boto3->speechkit) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio-tools
  Building wheel for grpcio-tools (setup.py) ... error 
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error 

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [122 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools
      copying grpc_tools\command.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools
      copying grpc_tools\protoc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools
      copying grpc_tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\wrappers.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\type.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\timestamp.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\struct.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\source_context.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\field_mask.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\empty.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\duration.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\descriptor.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler\plugin.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\api.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\any.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      running build_ext
      building 'grpc_tools._protoc_compiler' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_root
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_root\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_tools
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party 
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\cpp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\csharp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\java
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\js
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\objectivec
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\php
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\python
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\ruby
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\io
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\stubs
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\util
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\util\internal
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithi
rd_party\protobuf\src -IC:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\
MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows K
its\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\c
ppwinrt /EHsc /Tpgrpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.obj -std=c++14 /MT
      cl: командная строка warning D9025: переопределение "/MD" на "/MT"
      cl: командная строка warning D9002: пропуск неизвестного параметра "-std=c++14"
      python_generator.cc
      grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
      grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "const int"; возможна потеря данных
      grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(852): warning C4267: аргумент: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
      grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
      grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "const int"; возможна потеря данных
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithi
rd_party\protobuf\src -IC:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\
MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows K
its\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\c
ppwinrt /EHsc /Tpgrpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.obj -std=c++14 /MT
      cl: командная строка warning D9025: переопределение "/MD" на "/MT"
      cl: командная строка warning D9002: пропуск неизвестного параметра "-std=c++14"
      _protoc_compiler.cpp
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(113): warning C4005: MS_WIN64: изменение макроопределения
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp: note: см. предыдущее определение "MS_WIN64"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(2110): warning C4244: аргумент: преобразование "Py_ssize_t" в "int", возможна потеря данных
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8356): error C2027: использование неопределенного типа "_frame"
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note:  см. объявление "_frame"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9155): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9155): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9169): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem". 
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9171): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(10122): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(10124): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio-tools
  Running setup.py clean for grpcio-tools
Failed to build grpcio-tools 
Installing collected packages: grpcio-tools, cryptography, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, speechkit 
  Attempting uninstall: grpcio-tools
    Found existing installation: grpcio-tools 1.51.3 
    Uninstalling grpcio-tools-1.51.3: 
      Successfully uninstalled grpcio-tools-1.51.3 
  Running setup.py install for grpcio-tools ... error 
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error 

  × Running setup.py install for grpcio-tools did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [122 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools
      copying grpc_tools\command.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools
      copying grpc_tools\protoc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools
      copying grpc_tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\wrappers.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\type.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler\plugin.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\compiler
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\api.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      copying grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf\any.proto -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.11\grpc_tools\_proto\google\protobuf
      running build_ext
      building 'grpc_tools._protoc_compiler' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_root
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_root\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_tools
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\cpp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\csharp
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\java
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\js
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\objectivec
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\php
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\python
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\compiler\ruby
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\io
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\stubs
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\util
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\third_party\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\util\internal
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithi
rd_party\protobuf\src -IC:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\
MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows K
its\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\c
ppwinrt /EHsc /Tpgrpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.obj -std=c++14 /MT
      cl: командная строка warning D9025: переопределение "/MD" на "/MT"
      cl: командная строка warning D9002: пропуск неизвестного параметра "-std=c++14"
      python_generator.cc
      grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
      grpc_root\src/compiler/python_generator_helpers.h(104): warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "const int"; возможна потеря данных
      grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(852): warning C4267: аргумент: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
      grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
      grpc_root\src\compiler\python_generator.cc(893): warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "const int"; возможна потеря данных
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 -DMS_WIN64=1 -I. -Igrpc_root -Igrpc_root\include -Ithi
rd_party\protobuf\src -IC:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\
MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows K
its\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\c
ppwinrt /EHsc /Tpgrpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.11\Release\grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.obj -std=c++14 /MT
      cl: командная строка warning D9025: переопределение "/MD" на "/MT"
      cl: командная строка warning D9002: пропуск неизвестного параметра "-std=c++14"
      _protoc_compiler.cpp
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(113): warning C4005: MS_WIN64: изменение макроопределения
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp: note: см. предыдущее определение "MS_WIN64"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(2110): warning C4244: аргумент: преобразование "Py_ssize_t" в "int", возможна потеря данных
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(8356): error C2027: использование неопределенного типа "_frame"
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note:  см. объявление "_frame"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9155): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9155): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9169): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem" 
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9171): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9185): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9187): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9188): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"

      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9445): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9522): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9525): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9526): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9530): error C2027: использование неопределенного типа "_frame" 
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note:  см. объявление "_frame"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9561): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9567): error C2027: использование неопределенного типа "_frame"
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\pytypedefs.h(22): note:  см. объявление "_frame"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9873): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(9875): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem". 
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(10122): error C2039: "exc_type": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      grpc_tools\_protoc_compiler.cpp(10124): error C2039: "exc_traceback": не является членом "_err_stackitem".
      C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\cpython/pystate.h(55): note:  см. объявление "_err_stackitem"
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output] 

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Rolling back uninstall of grpcio-tools
  Moving to c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages\grpc_tools\ 
   from C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\~rpc_tools
  Moving to c:\users\berneons\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages\grpcio_tools-1.51.3.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\Berneons\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\~rpcio_tools-1.51.3.dist-info
error: legacy-install-failure 

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> grpcio-tools

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

i try update wheel, pip and other.
Delete folder with package.
Update Visual studio with C++ package

Answer (score 0):

The last supported Python version for speechkit is 3.10, so you also should use an older Python version to install it, e.g. `pip3.10 install speechkit`.